# Cacao tree: leaves falling off, some discolored

Tags: trees

Note that I'm a complete novice when it comes to gardening and I am asking this question on behalf on my girlfriend. This is a cacao tree.

**Problem 1**. Notice the following discoloration of the leaves:

[image]

The right leaf is a normal leaf, the left one is not-so-normal.

**Problem 2**. Combined with this, many of the leaves have been falling out lately. [That is a light bulb on the right of it, by the way.]

[image]

She has done the following to try to remedy the situation:

- Spraying the leaves with water (she suspects it's dehydration, since the A/C is on frequently over here)
- Keeping the tree away from direct sunlight (she suspects the leaves have been sunburned)

What is happening to the tree and what should be done to help it?

*Edit*: As requested by stormy:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your girlfriend's right - the AC could be causing a problem - its probably drying the air and causing temperatures that might just be a bit too low for the plant. Cacao is an understory plant from the Amazon rainforest - it doesn't mind a bit of dappled sunlight, but does not appreciate sun in a home, unless its just first thing in the morning or late in the day. It naturally prefers high humidity, more than 60%, which is quite difficult to achieve in a home environment - you haven't said where you are, but some areas have naturally low humidity anyway, never mind indoors. Placing the pot on a large tray filled with pebbles, and keeping the pebbles topped up with water so that they're half submerged, but not so the bottom of the pot is in the water, should help with humidity.

It also does not like to dry out, and should be kept quite moist, but not waterlogged - there's a balance to be struck, because too much water might cause fungal problems, particularly at the root, but not enough, and the leaves brown and shrivel. Note that some loss of leaves from the lower parts is quite normal.

This link provides more information and might be useful to you

http://science.psu.edu/news-and-events/lectures-and-events/frontiers/learning-resources/maximova-guiltinan_growing-chocolate_2-2014

Answer (score 1):

Your plant needs LOTS MORE light. Perhaps a good grow light would help.  I'd like to see the pot/soil of this plant. What I see is too much salt from using tap or city water.  Is your water softened?  That is salt.  Tips and edges of leaves will brown.  Is there white, crusty stuff on top of your soil? Quit using tap water and purchase distilled water to use instead.  I'd repot with new sterilized potting soil as well.  Send a picture of pot and soil, please. Keep this plant away from any drafts, especially air-conditioned.

Comment: All of the problems you've mentioned (including the white, crusty stuff) are there. Not sure if the water is softened but I've told her we will get distilled water. Do you have suggestions as to what I should look for when it comes to grow lights?

Comment: I've uploaded an image of the soil in the original post.

Comment: Could you please take a finger and pull back the soil away from the base of your plant?  I am looking for where roots begin.  Soil up on the stem/bark of this plant keeps moisture and bacteria where they can slowly kill this plant...grow lights.  I'll be back with a couple of suggestions.  Do you have other house plants?  Do you happen to have a covered porch?

Comment: Just pull that soil away from the bottom, I am seeing it might be buried too deeply.  Can't tell if the white on your soil is salt, but truly.  I won't DRINK tap water.